# Prove that the constructed shape is a square

Tags: geometry

We construct four squares outside a parallelogram on it's sides Prove that if we connect the centers of the squares we get a square.

**My attempt**:I connected the intersection of the parallelogram's diagonals to the centers by symmetry we can easily prove the shape is a parallelogram.But how to prove it is a square?
[image]

Comment: Join the centers of the squares with the nearest vertex of the parallelogram. Look at the triangles formed. You will be able to apply LAL to prove those triangles are equal. The equality of the sides of the triangles is easy. Each is half of the diagonal of one of the squares. The angle in between is equal to a right angle plus the angle of the parallelogram. To see this part you will need to use that the sum of to adjacent angles of a parallelogram sum up to two right angles.

Comment: @Bettybel Could you add a picture it is hard to understand this way.

Comment: Don't have a picture maker at hand. If you add one with labeled vertices I can name the triangles.

Comment: @Bettybel added.

Comment: Look at the triangles NBO and OAP. The sides NB and AP are equal since they are half of the diagonal of equal squares. For the same reason BO = OA.

Comment: Now compare the angles NBO and OAP. The angle NBO is equal to two 45 degrees angles plus the angle of the parallelogram at B. The angle OAP is also equal to two 45 degrees angles plus the angle IAK.

Comment: Notice that the angle IAK plus BAD sum 180. That means that IAK is equal to the angle of the parallelogram at B. Therefore the angles NBO and OAP are equal.

Comment: Now apply LAL to the triangles NBO and OAP. and conclude that NO = OP.

Answer (score 0):

[image: squares on a parallelogram]$A,B,C,D$ are centers of squares on the side of a parallelogram.  Prove figure $ABCD$ is a square.  Join $AE$, $AF$, $EB$, $FD$. Triangles $AEB$ and $AFD$ are congruent, since $AE = AF$, $EB = FD$, and $\angle AEB = \angle AFD$, each angle being a right angle ($45+45$) plus the supplement of the angle of the parallelogram at $F$. Therefore, $AB = AD$. And since $\angle EAB = \angle FAD$, then by addition $\angle EAF = \angle BAD$. But $\angle EAF$ is right. Therefore $\angle BAD$ is right. In this way we prove $ABCD$ is equilateral and right-angled.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z$, $w$, $-z$, $-w\in{\mathbb C}$ be the vertices of the parallelogram in counterclockwise order. The square over the edge $[z,w]$ then has vertices $v_0=z$, $v_1=z-i(w-z)$, $v_2=w+i(z-w)$, $v_3=w$ and center $$c={1\over4}(v_0+v_1+v_2+v_3)={1-i\over 2}(w+iz)\ .$$
The replacement $z\rightsquigarrow w$, $w\rightsquigarrow -z$ produces the next center
$$c'={1-i\over2}\bigl(-z+iw)=i c\ ,$$
and it becomes obvious that $c''=ic'$, $c'''=i c''$. All of this shows that the points $c$, $c'$, $c''$, $c'''$ form the vertices of a square.